# read.dta convert.dates not working?

Tags: regex, r, date, stata

I have a Stata dataset, call it `dataset.dta`. I want to read it in R. I am using the package `foreign`. Problem is it fails to parse/convert Stata dates to R dates.
It goes something like this:

```
df <- read.dta( 'dataset.dta', convert.dates = TRUE )
# Check attributes
attr( df, "formats")
"%9s"    "%8.0g"  "%12.0g" "%12.0g" "%9.0g"  "%21s"   "%31s"   "%td"    "%td"
# Last two columns are dates i.e. %td
str( df )
... # Only showing last two columns
$ start_sample: num  15494 14246 14246 14670 14245 ...
$ end_sample  : num  18262 18262 18262 18262 18262 ...
```

I was expecting `Date class` for these, instead of `num`. When I look into the source code of `read.dta` I find this.

```
if (convert.dates) {
    ff <- attr(rval, "formats")
    dates <- grep("%-*d", ff)
    base <- structure(-3653, class = "Date")
    for (v in dates) rval[[v]] <- base + rval[[v]]
}
```

Changing the third line here to `dates <- grep( "%*d", ff)` seems to take care of the issue. I changed the regex. I'm using Stata version 13.0.

Am I missing something? This just a bug or am I doing something woefully wrong here?

Comment: Try reading it in as character and then using `lubridate` to convert?

Comment: Which version of stata data do you use ? may be is related to https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2014-January/068271.html

Comment: @AriB.Friedman `lubridate` looks great. Will definitely use it in other projects. Thanks. For this issue, not entirely sure how it helps though.

Comment: This is a bit of hack. R stores dates as days since 01jan1970. Stata uses 01jan1960 as the base, so all you have to do is add the number of days between 01jan1970 and 01jan1960, which I believe is 3653.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two quick fixes/hacks. The first is

```
#### Convert to dates ####
datelookup <- format(seq(as.Date("1960-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by = "1 day"))
df$start_sample_ dates <- datelookup[ df$start_sample + 1]
df$start_sample_dates <- datelookup[ df$end_sample + 1]
```

Stata uses 01/01/1960 as the [base](http://blog.stata.com/2011/01/05/using-dates-and-times-from-other-software/). The second is

```
#### Stealing from foreign package ####
ff <- attr(df, "formats")
dates <- grep("%*d", ff)
base <- structure(-3653, class = "Date")
for (v in dates) df[[v]] <- base + df[[v]]
```

Why `structure(-3653, class = "Date")` ? See comment @Dimitriy V. Masterov above. This issue could be specific to Stata version 13.0. See comment @dickoa above. Thanks for your help.